# Sum/Average numbers in a single line - UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm working on a small script to take 3 numbers in a single line, sum and average them, and print the result at the end of the line. I know how to use the paste command, but everything I'm finding is telling me how to average a column. I need to average a line, not a column. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Any sample input ?

Comment: wouldn't it be just ($1 + $2 + $3)/3?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo 1 2 3 | awk -v RS=' ' '{sum+=$1; count++} END{print sum, sum/count}'
6 2
```

works for any number of input fields

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 | awk -v RS=' ' '{sum+=$1; count++} END{print sum, sum/count}'
10 2.5
```

Comment: Or Perl: `echo "1 2 3" | perl -pae '$_=eval(join"+",@F)/@F'`

Comment: @andlrc There's no need to provide translations of an answer into another language in the comments. If you feel a `perl` solution is better, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your line before giving it to `bc`. With `bc` you have additional possibilities such as setting the scale.
A simple mean from 1 2 3 would be

```
   echo "1 2 3"  | sed -e 's/\([0-9.]\) /\1+/g' -e 's/.*/(&)\/3/' | bc
```

You can wrap it in a function and see more possibilities:

```
function testit {

   echo "Input $@"
   echo "Integer mean"
   echo "$@"  | sed -e 's/\([0-9.]\) /\1+/g' -e 's/.*/(&)\/'$#'/' | bc

   echo "floating decimal mean"
   echo "$@"  | sed -e 's/\([0-9.]\) /\1+/g' -e 's/.*/(&)\/'$#'/' | bc -l

   echo "2 decimal output mean"
   echo "$@"  | sed -e 's/\([0-9.]\) /\1+/g' -e 's/.*/scale=2; (&)\/'$#'/' | bc
   echo
}

testit 4 5 6
testit 4 5 8
testit 4.2 5.3 6.4
testit 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```